# How to make an admin page to modify/add to a list, create new web pages, etc

Tags: php, html, oop, dynamic, admin

I want to add functionality to a website I am building for a client that allows him to log on to a secure page and add new job listings. He will be the only one modifying this so I don't need to worry about concurrent access or anything like that. At this point I don't even have a database set up for him but I understand that might need to be implemented soon, for other features if not this one.

He doesn't have any knowledge of HTML so I can't just create a template job posting and have him manually fill in the information (although that is also unprofessional, I suppose.) I was planning on just making a simple php/html page where he could put the title of the job along with all details through submission of a form. Once I have that, though, I don't know how to deal with adding that job title to a list of current job postings and also have that link to a new page with all the details of the job.

My memory from early undergraduate classes are hinting that the adding jobs to a list would be object-oriented. However, I can also see something where I would just add the title to an array which the list then dynamically filled from.

Another recommendation I have received is to look into implementing a django/python solution. The problem is I have about a week to work on this and I ahve no python experience. If that is something that would be possible to learn and implement in that time, I will go for it. I just don't want to waste time on something that takes a week or two to learn and then still have nothing implemented.

Basically, I would appreciate a point in the right direction and some reassurance that I am considering all possibilities. If it would be easier to implement some kind of simple wiki, that is another option as well.

Do any of these ideas sound like the right choice? Is there anything I am missing?

I apologize if this is a trivial question but I have stumped myself and would appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Look for any CMS with additional plugins that gets your job done.

Comment: Since you dont know about them, you should read about them in Wikipedia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible and easy solution would be using an appropriate CMS module, like [Job Manager](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/job-manager/) or [Resume Submissions and Job Posting](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/resume-submissions-job-postings/) for WordPress. I haven't tested them personally, but they should handle everything for you through a Web interface, no coding needed (you should just adapt the WordPress CSS to match the existing client's Website style).

---

For reference, here's what I would have done in case no such CMS module existed.

1. Create a database with a table that will hold all job postings. The table should have the following columns: `id`, `title`, `description`, `validityDate` (names are self-explanatory). Add more if appropriate.
2. Write a script that queries the database for all current job postings using the following query: `SELECT id, title FROM postings WHERE validityDate >= NOW()`. To manage database connections, use the PHP PDO extension (look at [its page on the PHP manual website](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for examples). This will return a list of all current job postings. For each result, let the script output HTML code like this: `echo "<a href=\"post.php?id=$id\">$title</a><br />$description";`, where `$id`, `$title` and `$description` are the variables holding the ID, title and description of the current record.
3. Write the `post.php` script that will fetch the details of the job posting with the ID specified in the id parameter.
4. Write another script where the client will input the details for a new posting into a form. After submission, the script should just insert the data into the table.

Comment: Good answer. However the author should look at something like WordPress, b2evolution, movabletype.. all free and very easy CMS - alternate to check out sites like CodeCanyon which sell simple CMS for designers/devs to give to clients - so solving your scenario. No for SO.

Comment: I thought at first the requirements were very specific and no suitable module existed - I've found some and am editing my answer right now.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Excuse my incompetence at this but how would I implement, say, wordpress if I wanted to. Would I use CSS to make the wordpress page look just like the rest of the site and then have each post be the new job? Would it still be possible for him to fill out a form which then submitted the details to this wordpress section and then added it to the jobs list?

Comment: @eliot Yes, you would use CSS to match the style of the site; as for the postings, there are specific modules that handle everything for you and create all pages automatically. See my updated answer.

Comment: @elgaton Wow that looks really good and exactly the set of features I need. My only concern is that my client wants a scrolling preview of the list of the most recent jobs on the home page. I don't think it would be appropriate to move the home page to wordpress and I don't even know if that is possible considering I have probably 8 javascript files being used and its quite complex. Is there any way around this or do you actually recommend moving it over to the WordPress site. If so, is it worth it to move my whole site over there/would I have to do that anyway?

Comment: @eliot If the client is using some CMS, it is worth searching if there are any specific modules for the software he's using. In case he's not using any CMS, I recommend you to download WordPress and install it locally on the client's Web server (for better performance and legal reasons). As for the scrolling preview, I haven't looked at the code of those modules, but generally they offer the possibility to show some of their data in a "box" or get it through an API; I suggest you to look at it (moving the site would be a huge task, although it would lead to clear advantages in the long term).